# Why is Web Deployment Agent Service (MsDepSvc) crashing with a FileNotFoundException?

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, webdeploy

I'm attempting to deploy a .NET 4 web application to a Windows 2008R2 server using Web Deploy V2. As part of this deployment we copy some batch files to the target machine. When I execute the command below, Web Deployment Agent Service (MsDepSvc) stops and a FileNotFoundException is logged to the system Application event log.

The web deploy command:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:contentPath="C:\work\27f84e3eca3a33d5\Output\BatchFiles" -dest:contentPath="c:_DeployCommands",computerName="192.168.1.14"

Full console output:

> C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy
>   V2\msdepl y.exe" -verb:sync
>   -source:contentPath="C:\work\27f84e3eca3a 3d5\Output\BatchFiles"
>   -dest:contentPath="c:_DeployCommands",computer ame="192.168.1.14" Info: Using ID '326b55b4-602c-4cdf-ae5c-052e9d44b377' for connections
>   to the remote server. Warning: Retrying the sync because a socket
>   error (10054) occurred. Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object
>   MSDeploy.contentPath (sourcePath). Attempt 1 of 25. Info: Using ID
>   'a6e468ca-53b9-474b-8568-42dba196bd72' for connections to the remote
>   server. Error Code: ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC More
>   Information: Could not connect to the destination computer
>   ("192.168.1.14"  using the specified process ("Web Deployment Agent
>   Service") because the serve  did not respond. Make sure that the
>   process ("Web Deployment Agent Service") i  started on the destination
>   computer. Error: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server
>   Unavailable. Error count: 1.

Event Log Entry:

> Application: MsDepSvc.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
>   The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
>   Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException Stack:    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Tracer.TraceError(Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentTraceSource,
>   System.String, System.Object[])    at
>   MSDepSvc.WDAgent.BeginProcessRequest(System.Net.HttpListenerContext)
>   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)    at
>   System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.IOCompleted(System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult,
>   UInt32, UInt32)    at
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32,
>   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)

How can I diagnose this?

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar issue. You're best bet is to decompile using ILSpy and add extra logging in every catch block and replace the exe on the client to see the exact error. In our scenario, we used on older version 7.1.1631.0 that works. There's a newer version 7.1.1762.0 that's caused the problem. The exe is copied from the client and not the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. It turned out to be a bug in Web Deploy 3.5 as described here: [Could not find file or assembly Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Tracing with Web Deploy V3 using tempagent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21121578/5810657)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer; I'm still new at this... Basically, the **Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Tracing** assembly is not found which leads to the crash as described above. In my case, it was because I was using the tempAgent feature, and the DLL is not copied over in v3.5.