# Could not find file or assembly Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Tracing with Web Deploy V3 using tempagent

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, web-deployment, msdeploy

I have been successfully using Web Deploy (MSDeploy) V2 with the tempagent option for some time. However, when I upgraded to V3 on the source machine, I received the following error:

> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: (12/18/2013 2:18:29 PM)
>   An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote
>   computer. ---> System.IO.IOException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Tracing, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Tracer.TraceMessage(TraceLevel level,
>   DeploymentTraceSource source, String message) at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData
>   asyncData) at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.BeginProcessRequest(DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest
>   workerRequest, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.GetHttpResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request) at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.CreateStatusThread(DeploymentSyncContext
>   syncContext) at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.RemoteDestSync(DeploymentObject
>   sourceObject, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext, Nullable`1 syncPass,
>   String syncSessionId) at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject
>   destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable
>   payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1
>   syncPassId, String syncSessionId) at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions
>   providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions,
>   DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions) at
>   MSDeploy.MSDeploy.ExecuteWorker()

The MS Deploy command looks like this:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package='MyPackage.zip' -dest:auto,computerName='MyServerName',tempAgent=true -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='MyWebAppName'
```

If verbose and debug are turned on, I can see that the temp agent files are copied to the remote server and a deployment is attempted. However, the Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Tracing dll is not copied.

Please note that I need to continue using temp agent and cannot install the Web Deployment Service on the target machines since I need to continue using IIS Share Config on those  servers and I would like to use V3 instead of V2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft. This is a bug that was introduced in 3.5. So, you basically cannot use tempAgent as intended at all in 3.5. It does seem to work in 3.0. So, I will be using that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Version 3.6 does not have this bug.